# Wiring new basement lights

Tags: wiring

I'm replacing an old light with an LED.  Old light is pull string so I'm adding a switch.  The light is connected directly to the power box/breaker.  Wiring is in conduit.

So I take the old light out, and wire the new one in.  Can I then run wiring to a wall and place a switch?  Pretty sure I can do this.

How about my next step.....can I then Run some line and have a second light using the same switch?  Or do I have to add a second switch?  So basically what I have is power source, to light, to switch.....to possible 2nd light

Answer (score 1):

Sure you can do that, as long as the total number of outlets on that circuit doesn't exceed the maximum allowed (In Canada we are allowed 12 on a 15A circuit) Since you're adding a light, you will be increasing the number of outlets on that circuit by 1, so you should count all the receptacles (each duplex receptacle counts as 1 outlet even if you're not presently using them) and lights on that circuit.

Comment: Should work the ...only thing on the breaker is that one ligt

Answer (score 1):

Sure. It's all pretty straight-forward. Here's your diagram. Notice how the white wire to the switch has been marked with black tape to indicate that it's a hot loop.

To add your second light, just connect by color in the original light box.

[image]
<sub>(source: [buildmyowncabin.com](http://www.buildmyowncabin.com/electrical/power-into-light-wiring.gif))</sub>